# Android: GridView image's from json

Tags: android, url, gridview, imageview

i have problem with ImageView into GridView, I parse JSON, and i take url from json and put it to my ImageView into GridView, and i have a error with this can you help me?

**LogCat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gazetaimage/com.gazetaimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5202)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gazetaimage.ImageAdapter.<init>(ImageAdapter.java:37)
    at com.gazetaimage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5106)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
    ... 11 more
```

**And my Code** In my AsyncTask i connect to my JSON file, and return JSONObject, and in ImageAdapter.class i get this object, and put into ImageView

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Context mContext;

    public String[] mThumbs;

    final static String TAG_ITEM = "item";
    final static String TAG_BIG_IMAGE = "big_image";

    public ImageAdapter (Context c){
        mContext = c;
        BackTask task = new BackTask();
        task.execute();

            try {

                JSONObject result = task.get();
                JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jrss = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    mThumbs[i] = jrss.getString(TAG_BIG_IMAGE);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     

            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) { 
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                 imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mThumbs[position]));

            return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you haven't initialized `mThubs`

Put the following line before looping through JSON array:

```
mThumbs = new String[jarray.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your null pointer exception is caused by mThumbs not being initialized so.
Check line 37 in your adapter.